# Jquery problem with height() and resize()

Tags: jquery, resize, height

I need to give an element a specific height based on document's height and keep it whether the document size changes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#descriptive_news_text').height(($(document).height() - 325));
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('#descriptive_news_text').height(($(document).height() - 325));
    });

});
```

Now, when I manually resize the browser it works like a charm, but at page load the document size is calculated in a wrong way so that the div's height is also wrong. I've tried to force a `$(windows).resize()` as last statement (as a test, even with a delay of seconds), but this doesn't work as jQuery only recognized the right height after a manual resize.

Also, resizing the window with a double click or via the "resize" button of the window (Chrome, Windows) it doesn't seem to trigger the "resize" event as dragging the window edges does.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To calculate the height, try replacing document by window:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#descriptive_news_text').height(($(window).height() - 325));
            $(window).resize(function () {
                    $('#descriptive_news_text').height(($(window).height() - 325));
            });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work fine for me:

```
$(function() {
    $("div#test").css("height", ($(document).height() - 325) + "px");
});
```