# JQuery: dynamic height() with window resize()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having an issue identical to this poster:
[Jquery problem with height() and resize()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931700/jquery-problem-with-height-and-resize)

But the solution doesn't fix my issue. I have three stacked divs, and I want to use JQuery to make the middle one adjust in height to 100% of the window height, minus the height (23px * 2) of the other top & bottom divs. It works on resize, but it's off (short) by 16px when the document initially loads.

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="bg1" class="bg">top</div>
<div id="content">
    help me. seriously.
</div>
<div id="bg2" class="bg">bottom</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.bg {
width:315px;
height:23px;
margin:0 auto;
text-indent:-9000px;
}

#bg1 {background:url(../images/bg1.png) 0 50% no-repeat;}
#bg2 {background:url(../images/bg2.png) 0 50% no-repeat;}

#content {
width:450px; 
margin:0 auto;
text-align: center;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    resizeContent();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        resizeContent();
    });
});

function resizeContent() {
    $height = $(window).height() - 46;
    $('body div#content').height($height);
}
```

Comment: I you looking for something like this? Or should the footer move with the page? http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/basics2.html A fiddle would be nice!

Comment: I could do something like that, but I'm stuck with the HTML that will be generated server-side. I've been asked to solve this sort of issue with JQuery.

Comment: What's with the 9000px text indent?

Comment: See "Using Text Indent to Hide Text": http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/text-indent

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I feel like there should be a no javascript solution, but how is this?

http://jsfiddle.net/NfmX3/2/

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#content').height($(window).height() - 46);
});

$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: Actually, you can do it in a single line. Even shorter!

Comment: I think you'll find the following is better/more dynamic:
`$('#dataview').height($(window).height() - $('#dataview').offset().top - 10);`

Answer (score 7):

Okay, how about a CSS answer! We use `display: table`. Then each of the divs are rows, and finally we apply height of 100% to middle 'row' and voilà.

http://jsfiddle.net/NfmX3/3/

```
body { display: table; }
div { display: table-row; }
#content {
    width:450px; 
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Man! I knew there was a CSS only solution! You inspired me. Guys, prefer this non-JS solution before any JS one. It's not as clean and you might need to use some extra mark-up, but still worth it.

Comment: Why do people think CSS is always better than JS?

Comment: @barell It isn't always better, but where it concerns presentation it's generally preferable to use styling alone, instead of implementing behaviour/logic as well. An additional benefit is that CSS is resilient by design, whereas JavaScript is brittle by design.

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest solution - also purely CSS - would be using calc and vh.

The middle div's heigh will be calculated thusly:

```
#middle-div { 
height: calc(100vh - 46px); 
}
```

That is, 100% of the viewport height minus the 2*23px.
This will ensure that the page loads properly and is dynamic[(demo here)](https://jsfiddle.net/vfjtzsd2/2/).

Also remember to use box-sizing, so the paddings and borders don't make the divs outfill the viewport.

Comment: Virtually all current browsers support calc (here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)
And same for vh (here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Answer (score 0):

To see the window height while (or after) it is resized, try it:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
$('body').prepend('<div>' + $(window).height() - 46 + '</div>');
});
```