# How to increase height of DIV based on content when height of DIV is defined by browser height with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, browser, resize, height

I am using the jQuery code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130946/jquery-dynamic-height-with-window-resize) post to make my DIV's height adjust according to the browser's height, and it is working just fine. What I am struggling with is to adjust this code so that it only adjusts to the browser's height when the content itself is not large enough to do so. At the moment, if you have content in the DIV that would naturally be taller than the browser's height, the jQuery code still makes the DIV only as tall as the browser window, cutting of the overflowing content.

The jQuery code I am using to make the DIV adjust height based on the browser's height:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    resizeContent();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        resizeContent();
    });
});

function resizeContent() {
    $height = $(window).height() - 0;
    $('body div.slide').height($height);
}
```

If anyone has any ideas as to how the code can be modified to keep it from cutting off the the content that is taller than the browser window, I would be forever grateful.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: show please also your html and css

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding your question, all you need to do is test the height of the div before setting applying the window height:

```
if ($('body div.slide').height()<=$height) {
  $('body div.slide').height($height);
}
```

see jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9YQYt/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the jsfiddle shows an error, and the same error occurs when I tried to apply the code to my project.

Comment: Just to clarify: The jQuery code that sets the height of the DIV according to the browser's height (and changes height if it is resized). However, if the content within this DIV is greater than the browser's height, the DIV still remains only as tall as the browser, meaning the excess content is not displayed. What I want is for the DIV only to fit the browser's height if the content is not great enough to fill it. If it is, the DIV can be of greater height than the browser.

Comment: What error are you receiving from the jsfiddle and what browser are you using? The excess content can only be displayed by using the vertical scroll bar and the jQuery code shown does not handle the window resize event.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve your problem with CSS if I understand the question

```
div.slide{height: 100%}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this, but it does not seem to have any impact on the problem. I am assuming the jQuery code is simple overriding this demand, as it tells the DIV not to be greater than the browser's height.

Comment: well, I misunderstood the question