# Can't add maxHeight into function to add and re-size the height of a class

Tags: jquery, html, css

My goal is to re-size a div with the class .pane-documentation-tree-menu. And I've achieved this, but only with a fixed height, if I try to add a **maxHeight** it doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.pane-documentation-tree-menu').height(($(window).height() - 150 + "px"));
    $(window).resize(function () {
      $('.pane-documentation-tree-menu').height(($(window).height() - 150 + "px"));
    });
  });
```

**Background:**
I was looking for a solution to this problem and encountered this post here [Jquery problem with height() and resize()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931700/jquery-problem-with-height-and-resize) and it worked, but when I tried to add maxHeight it stoped working.

Comment: Since you are using JQuery, I'd recommend that you add `jquery` to your tags to tell people what they have to expect. People who are working with native JS most likely won't be able to help you here, but still get drawn to this question.

Comment: @Robidu Thanks!, sorry I didn't noticed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set both height and max-height you can simply just use jQuery CSS, something like this:

```
function setMaxHeight() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    $('.pane-documentation-tree-menu').css({
        'max-height': windowHeight - 150,
        'height': windowHeight - 150
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    setMaxHeight();
});

$(window).on('resize', function(){
    setMaxHeight();
});
```

Comment: Great! it worked perfectly, just made a minor tweak so that it's always maxHeight and voalá. Thank you.